# How do you package TFS in your build with Object Model?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, object-model

I wrote software that connects to TFS via Microsoft libraries (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.x). The program runs great on my dev machine, but when I run the build on other machines, I get an error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client'" After research, I found there is a TFS object model that can assist in releasing this software on computers that do not have VS or MTM installed. However, there seem to be no guidelines on how to use it. How would I be able to build this software so it can use TFS on computers without Visual Studio installed?

Answer (score 2):

Use NuGet. Microsoft has the Team Foundation Server object model available as a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/14.89.0).

Comment: Will this allow me to bundle it into a single .exe that can run on any computer (assuming the correct .NET installed)? Or will you still need to install something on computers without the TFS library?

Comment: Bundling assemblies together is a different story. You can look into something like ILMerge.